# JS dynamic json array creation is not working in IE 11

Tags: javascript, json, internet-explorer-11

I have to make a dynamic `JSON array` using JavaScript.

My code is like

```
var item_id=document.getElementById(vendor_id+"item-id"+i).innerHTML;
var quantity=document.getElementById(vendor_id+"quantity"+i).value;
var unit_price=document.getElementById(vendor_id+"unit-price"+i).innerHTML;
var sub_total=document.getElementById(vendor_id+"price"+i).innerHTML;

item={
      item_id: item_id,
      quantity: quantity,
      price: unit_price,
      sub_total: sub_total
     }
console.log(item.item_id);
products.push(item);
```

When I run this on chrome, I am getting the item array, also getting the console print item_id.
But when I run this on `IE 11` the console print is `undefined`

```
item.item_id is undefined
```

How can I change this to work in all browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried logging vendor_id and i? Maybe the string for getElementById is different from what you expected and selecting the element is not working.

On the other hand, are you sure you want to optimize your website for IE11? I think Microsoft will drop support this year. It probably isn‘t worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you should declare item first like:

```
var item = {
      item_id:item_id,
      quantity:quantity,
      price:unit_price,
      sub_total:sub_total
     }
```